# typescript add property to class in a type safe way

Tags: typescript

I want to monkey patch a Class in Typescript and add a property to it. I'm able to do this but I do not know how to do this in a type safe way (if this is possible at all).

This is my code:

```js
function extended(target: any) {
  
  const newProperty: string = 'hello';
  target.prototype.newProperty = newProperty;
  
}


@extended
class Test {
  
}

const test = new Test();

// compiler telling property 'newProperty' does not exist on type 'Test'.
console.log(test?.newProperty)
```

Here I'm trying it with a decorator, however I'm also fine with any other solution to add a property to a class when it is possible to get type safety.

Here's a link to a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWAJsrAKKAQwCcBzZKALkULAE8BKRAbwChFF3EIEBnKRGGQB3AArE4AB2TEodav2IwwpRAF5EAcgAWyADZ64mgNxciZCgDpJEqHDnTLQsROmy66wSPFSZc0xysAL6soQACaBjYuKwQeoS8vIgAKsj8LFzBoTxg6RjpGs4paVB4DKaxfHB6yJaGpAQlAPxO3q5+jEA)

Comment: Decorators won't mutate the type as seen by the compiler. Will mixins work for you instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N71QBW) maybe?  (Adding a string to the prototype is strange, and not easily done with `class` notation, but you [can do it](https://tsplay.dev/Nrnj2N) if you must).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz mixins I do not want to use as it is more or less just inheritence. I want to enhance a class without "loosing" the ability to extend from another class in future. Adding the string to the class is just a very simplified example what I really want to do :). But you wrote that "Decorators won't mutate the type as seen by the compiler" - that means it is not possible what I want to achieve.

Comment: @TobiasS. yes, it is pointing out the same anwser as jcalz did - it's not possible (unfortunately :( )